# POSTING a response to an external url in php

Tags: php, forms, post, response, payment

Im having a site where I get the payment response sent out by the payment processor.My page is https and whereas my customers page is not.

I post the payment response this way

```
echo '<html>Redirecting to merchants website..<body>
<form id="myForm" action="'.$response_url.'" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="'.$response['status'].'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="customerReferenceNo" value="'.$data['customerReferenceNo'].'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$data['amount'].'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="paymentMode" value="'.$data['paymentMode'].'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cardProvider" value="'.$data['cardProvider'].'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="orderID" value="'.$orderID.'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mobileNo" value="'.$mobileNo.'"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$email.'"/>
</form>

<script>document.getElementById("myForm").submit();</script></body></html>';
```

as an hidden form post.But as Iam posting the values from an https to an http page,its popping up security warning in some browser as:

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent
>   over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?

I wonder if this is the correct way to post a response to an external url?Is what Iam doing is right?Is this th exact way I should post a payment response to an external url?

Please help out with some suggestion

Comment: You're loading the form on an `https://...` page, but are submitting it to `http://` (**no** S). You'll get that warning anytime you're submitting secure->insecure, even if that insecure is some completely foreign page. It's a security mechanism, and you should NOT bypass it.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the user back to the response url or just inform the response url that the payment was made?

Comment: I wanted to post the data to the external url as well as redirect to it..

Comment: @Kypros As I post my customers can show the payment status in the oage Im redirecting to

Comment: That warning is in place by the browser for security and for good reason. It should be there. What you should be doing is using something like CURL to post the payment result to a page on the http site that just records the payment result. Then redirect them back to the other site where their status can be checked. Usually by an id. When they get redirected to your site for processing, have the other site send you a unique id for their customer. Then post that id back with response. Redirect to other site and they should have the id.

Comment: You should read over another payment processor API such as PayPal to see how they handle payment responses. But when posting a form from https->http you will always get an error like this and you can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above you should definitely take care to post back to a https site. But instead of outputting a hidden form to the browser and posting from there it would be way better to use curl and so sent the data directly from the server to the payment processor.
See [curl_exec in php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding what you said.If I post the response to the url they gave using curl,and then redirect using header or what ever to the saem url,wil they be able to show the response I am passing?

Comment: It might depend on the payment service and what you want to show after posting the data. You will get the result back in your php code. I am of course not sure what the result will be. So either some information you can display or an url you could redirect to.